# curl fail to set header application/json php

Tags: php, curl

My goal is to connect a private web service on my job.
Im trying to connect but when I set Content-Type to application/json it fails and return null, someone can help?
 This is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8')
        );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$fp = fopen(WAREHOUSE . '/errorlogc.txt', 'w');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

when I execute this code it fails and return null and no more info, even the log I set for it show's me nothing.

Comment: "when I set Content-Type to application/json" — I don't see any attempt to do that in the code you shared.

Comment: … and you have a lot of undefined variables there. You're [mcve] does need to be complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed! the problem was that before trying to send data to the server I have to set a cookie for the session, so I get the cookie from the header response on the connection and then send the data.

thanks for the help